# Configure supported language on mcamara/laravel-localization

Tags: php, configuration, composer-php, laravel-5.1

I installed [mcamara/laravel-localization](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization) via composer and try now to configure the [supported locales](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization#config). There I run in the issue that:

1. `app/providers/ConfigServicePovider.php` does not exists in L5.1
2. `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\LaravelLocalizationServiceProvider"` result in: Nothing to publish for tag []
3. and on `config/app.php` it's not clear to me what to do

*Regarding 1.* I am not sure if I can just create it and it works. My feeling is this will not work.

*Regarding 2.* its the same result if I run just: `php artisan vendor:publish". I am working on Windows, so I am not sure if I have to run the command in a different way. Perhaps regarding the path...

**Can anybody help me how to configure the *Supported Locales*?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by copying the config manually

```
cp vendor/mcamara/laravel/lacalization/src/config/config.php config/laravellocalization.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a step by step instruction for installing mcamara/laravel-localization hope this helps.

Install `mcamara/laravel-localization` using

```
composer.phar require potsky/laravel-localization-helpers
```

Add the following

`Potsky\LaravelLocalizationHelpers\LaravelLocalizationHelpersServiceProviderLaravel5::class,` to `config/app.php` at the end of `providers` array like this

```
'providers' => [
Potsky\LaravelLocalizationHelpers\LaravelLocalizationHelpersServiceProviderLaravel5::class,
]
```

You can also add an alias in the `aliases` array in the config/app.php.

```
'aliases' => [
'LaravelLocalization'   => Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Facades\LaravelLocalization::class
]
```

Now this should appear in output of `php artisan list`

```
 localization
  localization:find     Display all files where the argument is used as a lemma
  localization:missing  Parse all translations in app directory and build all lang files
```

Now try `php artisan vendor:publish` it should output something like this:

```
Copied File [/vendor/potsky/laravel-localization-helpers/src/config/config-laravel5.php] To [/config/laravel-localization-helpers.php]
Publishing complete for tag []!
```

Comment: Installion `mcamara/laravel-localization` is not the problem. I struggle with the configuration of `supported locales`. How do I do this with `potsky/laravel-localization-helpers`? I want to configure `en` and `ar`

Comment: Once you have installed it you could see the Usage section of this https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization

Comment: The question I raised was about the configuration, as it did not work as documented. Have solved it.